# Python raw_input use TAB instead of ENTER?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tabs, enter, raw-input

I've made this little script to handle a CSV export from my store's point of sale. It takes a list of barcodes entered by our barcode scanner. Then looks up those items in a list to quickly check our physical inventory from what the point of sale claims we have.

It works... what I'm curious is if I can change raw_input from it's default use of ENTER and replace it with TAB?

My barcode scanner is programmed to use a TAB after it scans a barcode (as our POS demands that it does), would make it real handy to not have to man the keyboard while scanning items.

Is it possible?

```
import csv

inv = csv.reader(open('onhand.tab', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")

invarray = []
countlist = []

for row in inv:
    invarray.append(row)

print "Input barcode followed by <ENTER>. When finished, 'x' followed by <ENTER>"
while True:
    bb = raw_input('> ')
    countlist.append(bb)
    if bb == 'x':
        break

print "\n" * 100
print "+" + "-" * 130 + "+"

for row in invarray:
    barcode = row[0]
    prod_name = row[8]
    main = row[4]
    vb = row[12]
    oo = row[6]
    toh = row[9]
    mnum = row[5]

    for row in countlist:
        bc = row[0]
        if bc == barcode:
            print ('|%-15s\t%-100s\t%-3s|') % (barcode, prod_name, main)
            print "+" + "-" * 130 + "+"
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot; `raw_input()` only returns control when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> has been entered.

Read directly from [`sys.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) directly instead:

```
barcode = []
while True:
    char = sys.stdin.read(1)  # read 1 character from stdin
    if char == '\t':  # if a tab was read
        break
    barcode.append(char)
countlist.append(''.join(barcode))
```

Comment: You are appending single characters from the barcode to countlist, instead of adding the barcode as a whole.