# TAB Key in Python

Tags: python, unix, tabs

I'm working on a Python application that asks the user for two inputs, but in order for them to go to the next input, they need to hit ENTER/RETURN, is it possible to also use the TAB key?

Right now, if the user hits TAB, it'll just add a space to the text.

[EDIT] I did try the sys.stdin method but all I get is a blank screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450180/change-the-focus-from-one-text-widget-to-another -- think this might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python raw\_input use TAB instead of ENTER?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084223/python-raw-input-use-tab-instead-of-enter)

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084223/python-raw-input-use-tab-instead-of-enter), if you use `raw_input` or `input` it is not possible and you would have to read from `stdin` directly

```
import sys


def input_with_tab():
    text = ""
    while True:
        char = sys.stdin.read(1)  # read 1 character from stdin
        if char == '\t':  # if a tab was read
            break
        text += char

    return text

print("Write something:")
text = input_with_tab()
print(text)
```

Comment: that showed me a blank screen and nothing else works.

Comment: that somewhat works, but now it gets weird, if I type in the text and hit ENTER, it creates and new like, if I hit TAB and then ENTER, it will break and print(text).

Comment: Yep, I played around a bit. The problem seems to be that the charactes will only be sent when enter is pressed, not immediately after keydown.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry I am actually stuck here